# initial `reactive ` value to null

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

everybody.
I have a question about using `reactive`. I know the type of a state, but the initial value is empty. How do I use assignment? The code is as follows

```
//....
  let origin = reactive<Timeslot | {}>({});
  const handler = (data) => {
       Object.assign(origin, data);
  };
//..
```

In fact, I want to assign the initial value of `origin` to `null`. How can I deal with this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to assign `null` to an reactive, as reactive signature requires [the type extends an object](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/basic-reactivity.html#reactive):

```js
function reactive<T extends object>(target: T): UnwrapNestedRefs<T>
```

With that said, why do you want a null reactive ? You wouldn't be able to benefit from vue's reactivity system if you initialize a reactive with `null` or even an empty object (even though this is possible), as you are not tracking anything in that case.

Perhaps what you need is a ref ? You can make a ref nullable with a nullable union type like so.

```js
let origin = ref<Timeslot | null>(null);
```

Comment: Will the Timeslot's properties be reactive in this case? Shouldn't reactive() be used for objects?

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the issue of how to best handle a reactive object with a default empty (null or `{}` or similar) value.